# query total reduced by percent

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys I have some query problem. I want to reduced my total with percentage but this code give me some error:

```
SELECT `id_sewa`,`nama_villa`,DATE_FORMAT(`tgl_transaksi`, '%d-%m-%Y'),`nama_tamu`,`cek_in`,`cek_out`, datediff(`cek_out`,`cek_in`) as rn,format(`harga`, 0),format(datediff(`cek_out`,`cek_in`) *`harga`, 0)as total,`ref`,
(
CASE
WHEN ref = "direct" THEN format(datediff(`cek_out`,`cek_in`) * `harga`, 0) - 10%
END) AS total_bersih

from sewa_villa
where tgl_transaksi BETWEEN '2017-11-12' and '2017-11-14';
```

My expectation:

```html
<table border =1>
<tr>
<th>total</th>
<th>ref</th>
<th>total bersih</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>2,000,000</th>
<th>direct</th>
<th>1,800,000</th>
</table>
```

This the error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS total_bersih
from sewa_villa where tgl_transaksi BETWEEN '2017-11-12' and ' at line 6
```

Comment: Addf some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text please, not images.)

Comment: show also the exact error message

Comment: `- 10%` = `* 0.9`

Comment: Given your desired output you should add `AND ref = "direct"` at the end. That way you won't need case, just formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your "-10%" :

```
SELECT `id_sewa`,`nama_villa`,DATE_FORMAT(`tgl_transaksi`, '%d-%m-%Y'),`nama_tamu`,`cek_in`,`cek_out`, datediff(`cek_out`,`cek_in`) as rn,format(`harga`, 0),format(datediff(`cek_out`,`cek_in`) *`harga`, 0)as total,`ref`,
(
CASE
WHEN ref = "direct" THEN format(datediff(`cek_out`,`cek_in`) * `harga`, 0) *0.9
END) AS total_bersih

from sewa_villa
where tgl_transaksi BETWEEN '2017-11-12' and '2017-11-14';
```

Just a note : you didn't put any else in the case/when, are your sure about it ?

Comment: thank a lot dude this so help me solved my problem but i need to change my  round brackets a little bit and the query is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use percentage calculation on MySQL directly (using something like `- 10%`)! You have to replace `- 10%` with `* 0.9` as I already mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280864/query-total-reduced-by-percent/47281266#comment81512561_47280864):

```
SELECT 
    `id_sewa`,
    `nama_villa`,
   DATE_FORMAT(`tgl_transaksi`, '%d-%m-%Y'),
   `nama_tamu`,
   `cek_in`,
   `cek_out`,
   DATEDIFF(`cek_out`,`cek_in`) AS rn,
   FORMAT(`harga`, 0),
   FORMAT(DATEDIFF(`cek_out`,`cek_in`) * `harga`, 0) AS total,
   `ref`, (
       CASE
           WHEN ref = "direct" THEN FORMAT(DATEDIFF(`cek_out`, `cek_in`) * `harga`, 0) * 0.9
       END) AS total_bersih
FROM sewa_villa
WHERE tgl_transaksi BETWEEN '2017-11-12' AND '2017-11-14';
```

---

**The `%` can be used as following:**

- wildcard operator (`col_name LIKE '%test%'`)
- on a [modulo operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod) (`col_name % 5`).

In your case: MySQL try to calculate a modulo operation but the number after the `%` is missing. This is the reason why MySQL throws an error.

Comment: thanks dude it help me but the first one answering right too i still can't give a good voting for you guys because my reputation not give me a permission